# Get location of a DLL within solution in C# under Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-assembly

Suppose I have below directory structure in my visual studio 2008 solution explorer:

```
+ MyDomain.ConsoleApps.MyApp
   |
   | 
   + Properties
   + References
   + bin
   + Resources
        |
        + Embedded
             |
             -- ThirdPartyLibrary.dll
```

ThirdPartyLibrary.dll is an embedded resource (compilation action is set to embedded) so at runtime I load this library using below method:

```
    public static System.Reflection.Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {            
        Assembly a1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream s = a1.GetManifestResourceStream("MyDomain.ConsoleApps.MyApp.Resources.Embedded.ThirdPartyLibrary.dll");
        byte[] block = new byte[s.Length];
        s.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
        Assembly a2 = Assembly.Load(block);
        return a2;
    }
```

and it works, but now instead of indicating the entire string location:

```
"MyDomain.ConsoleApps.MyApp.Resources.Embedded.ThirdPartyLibrary.dll"
```

I would like to obtain automatically by indicating ThirdPartyLibrary.dll in some way and pass it to GetManifestResourceStream.

So, how to do it?

Comment: @HansPassant What? embedding the assembly? because I want a single executable file, so I embed it. Also for loading assembly at runtime there is no other way to do it? or is there any better way? If so, please post an example. I need to pass the entire location in order the assembly loads correctly at runtime. Please see https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Embed%20DotNetZip&referringTitle=Examples . There is explained.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, and once I have the file added in resource designer, using my code above, how can I load this file using GetManifestResourceStream? or I have to load in any other way? could you provide a snipet code?

Comment: Ok, so all the above code for method Resolver may be reduced only to one line: Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.Whatever) Am I right? and then I reference it in my project to use it, right? I have done so and it is working. Another things, my project also depends on another projects so I add a reference for each of them, so could I do the same for them? I want to get only an executable (my console application) and all the dlls within it embedded. I suppose I can do the same. right?